# How to generate a proper playOrder in NCX files (used for epubs) in XQuery?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I struggle with a very specific thing—generating of NCX files for epubs. The problem is in the `playOrder` attribute of every `navPoint` element because the number is usually simply increasing without any importance of nesting. On the other hand, the file is naturally generated with iterating over nested elements (which denies simple usage of `at $count` counting style). I tried to generate this with iteration over an **array** of chapters directly, and I tried to generate it from the ready `toc` file as well (maybe easier because I iterate over one node, not the array). The problem was the same.

Sample part of NCX file:

```
<ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1">
    <head>
        <meta name="dtb:uid" content=""/>
        <meta name="dtb:depth" content="1"/>
        <meta name="dtb:totalPageCount" content="0"/>
        <meta name="dtb:maxPageNumber" content="0"/>
    </head>
    <docTitle>
        <text/>
    </docTitle>
    <navMap>
        <navPoint id="title-page" playOrder="1">
            <navLabel>
                <text>Title Page</text>
            </navLabel>
            <content src="title-page.xhtml"/>
        </navPoint>
        <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch1lev1" playOrder="@@@">
            <navLabel>
                <text>ÚVOD</text>
            </navLabel>
            <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch1lev1"/>
            <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev1" playOrder="@@@">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>Přehled bádání nad nálezy terry sigillaty v Čechách</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev1"/>
            </navPoint>
            <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev2" playOrder="@@@">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>Poválečné bádání nad nálezy terry sigillaty v evropském barbariku</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev2"/>
            </navPoint>
            <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev3" playOrder="@@@">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>Terminologie a tvarová klasifikace</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev3"/>
            </navPoint>
        </navPoint>
        <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch1lev1" playOrder="@@@">
            <navLabel>
                <text>KATALOG</text>
            </navLabel>
            <content src="chapter-2.xhtml#anch1lev1"/>
            <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev1" playOrder="@@@">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>Struktura a metodické pojetí katalogu</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev1"/>
            </navPoint>
            <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev2" playOrder="@@@">
                <navLabel>
```

Here I have the `playOrder` attribute only as a placeholder. Is there some easy way how to replace the `@@@` with simply increasing counter (per every `navPoint`)? I have tried `typeswitch` (was not able to make it work) and exhaustive counting of preceding levels of headings—it worked but was **extremely** clumsy and slow with increasing levels of headings, and very unstable across documents because of slightly variable xpath axes. I need a simple, bulletproof way. I guess counting of many preceding levels is not the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In approaching this problem myself I would probably try to generate the right value when first creating the NCX file. But if the challenge is how to fix the `playOrder` attributes on a file where the values are full of empty, dummy, or otherwise incorrect attributes, I can think of two techniques: use the XQuery typeswitch expression to iterate through all the nodes in the document and swap in the desired values, or use XQuery Update to surgically update the values. In my examples of each below, both take the same approach: use the `ancestor` and `preceding` XPath axes to calculate the value for the `playOrder` attribute. Note: my only change to your sample XML was to close the final elements in order to make it well-formed.

**Update**: In my first version I mistakenly omitted the `ancestor` axis count, leading to incorrect values. I had forgotten that the `preceding` axis doesn't include the `ancestor` axis. This is clear from my favorite diagram of XPath axes, https://our.umbraco.org/media/upload/0562fd58-c6db-4fa8-a432-68b28f11c3f2/rs/7x1B0.gif.

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace ncx="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/";

declare function local:fix-playorder($nodes as item()*) {
    for $node in $nodes
    return
        typeswitch ($node)
            case element(ncx:navPoint) return
                <navPoint xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/">{
                    $node/@*[not(name(.) = 'playOrder')],
                    attribute playOrder { count($node/ancestor::ncx:navPoint) + count($node/preceding::ncx:navPoint) + 1 },
                    local:fix-playorder($node/node())
                }</navPoint>
            case element() return
                element {node-name($node)} {$node/@*, local:fix-playorder($node/node())}
            default return
                $node
};

let $ncx := 
    <ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1">
        <head>
            <meta name="dtb:uid" content=""/>
            <meta name="dtb:depth" content="1"/>
            <meta name="dtb:totalPageCount" content="0"/>
            <meta name="dtb:maxPageNumber" content="0"/>
        </head>
        <docTitle>
            <text/>
        </docTitle>
        <navMap>
            <navPoint id="title-page" playOrder="1">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>Title Page</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="title-page.xhtml"/>
            </navPoint>
            <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch1lev1" playOrder="@@@">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>ÚVOD</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch1lev1"/>
                <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev1" playOrder="@@@">
                    <navLabel>
                        <text>Přehled bádání nad nálezy terry sigillaty v Čechách</text>
                    </navLabel>
                    <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev1"/>
                </navPoint>
                <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev2" playOrder="@@@">
                    <navLabel>
                        <text>Poválečné bádání nad nálezy terry sigillaty v evropském barbariku</text>
                    </navLabel>
                    <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev2"/>
                </navPoint>
                <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev3" playOrder="@@@">
                    <navLabel>
                        <text>Terminologie a tvarová klasifikace</text>
                    </navLabel>
                    <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev3"/>
                </navPoint>
            </navPoint>
            <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch1lev1" playOrder="@@@">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>KATALOG</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-2.xhtml#anch1lev1"/>
                <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev1" playOrder="@@@">
                    <navLabel>
                        <text>Struktura a metodické pojetí katalogu</text>
                    </navLabel>
                    <content src="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev1"/>
                </navPoint>
                <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev2" playOrder="@@@">
                    <navLabel/>
                </navPoint>
            </navPoint>
        </navMap>
    </ncx>
return
    local:fix-playorder($ncx)
```

The results:

```
<ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1">
    <head>
        <meta name="dtb:uid" content=""/>
        <meta name="dtb:depth" content="1"/>
        <meta name="dtb:totalPageCount" content="0"/>
        <meta name="dtb:maxPageNumber" content="0"/>
    </head>
    <docTitle>
        <text/>
    </docTitle>
    <navMap>
        <navPoint id="title-page" playOrder="1">
            <navLabel>
                <text>Title Page</text>
            </navLabel>
            <content src="title-page.xhtml"/>
        </navPoint>
        <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch1lev1" playOrder="2">
            <navLabel>
                <text>ÚVOD</text>
            </navLabel>
            <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch1lev1"/>
            <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev1" playOrder="3">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>Přehled bádání nad nálezy terry sigillaty v Čechách</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev1"/>
            </navPoint>
            <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev2" playOrder="4">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>Poválečné bádání nad nálezy terry sigillaty v evropském barbariku</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev2"/>
            </navPoint>
            <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev3" playOrder="5">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>Terminologie a tvarová klasifikace</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev3"/>
            </navPoint>
        </navPoint>
        <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch1lev1" playOrder="6">
            <navLabel>
                <text>KATALOG</text>
            </navLabel>
            <content src="chapter-2.xhtml#anch1lev1"/>
            <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev1" playOrder="7">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>Struktura a metodické pojetí katalogu</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev1"/>
            </navPoint>
            <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev2" playOrder="8">
                <navLabel/>
            </navPoint>
        </navPoint>
    </navMap>
</ncx>
```

An XQuery Update approach would use the same `preceding` axis technique. My example here is for eXist's XQuery Update implementation, which requires that the file be stored in the database. The resulting document is identical to the results above.

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare namespace ncx="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/";

let $ncx := 
    <ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1">
        <head>
            <meta name="dtb:uid" content=""/>
            <meta name="dtb:depth" content="1"/>
            <meta name="dtb:totalPageCount" content="0"/>
            <meta name="dtb:maxPageNumber" content="0"/>
        </head>
        <docTitle>
            <text/>
        </docTitle>
        <navMap>
            <navPoint id="title-page" playOrder="1">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>Title Page</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="title-page.xhtml"/>
            </navPoint>
            <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch1lev1" playOrder="@@@">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>ÚVOD</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch1lev1"/>
                <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev1" playOrder="@@@">
                    <navLabel>
                        <text>Přehled bádání nad nálezy terry sigillaty v Čechách</text>
                    </navLabel>
                    <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev1"/>
                </navPoint>
                <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev2" playOrder="@@@">
                    <navLabel>
                        <text>Poválečné bádání nad nálezy terry sigillaty v evropském barbariku</text>
                    </navLabel>
                    <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev2"/>
                </navPoint>
                <navPoint id="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev3" playOrder="@@@">
                    <navLabel>
                        <text>Terminologie a tvarová klasifikace</text>
                    </navLabel>
                    <content src="chapter-1.xhtml#anch2lev3"/>
                </navPoint>
            </navPoint>
            <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch1lev1" playOrder="@@@">
                <navLabel>
                    <text>KATALOG</text>
                </navLabel>
                <content src="chapter-2.xhtml#anch1lev1"/>
                <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev1" playOrder="@@@">
                    <navLabel>
                        <text>Struktura a metodické pojetí katalogu</text>
                    </navLabel>
                    <content src="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev1"/>
                </navPoint>
                <navPoint id="chapter-2.xhtml#anch2lev2" playOrder="@@@">
                    <navLabel/>
                </navPoint>
            </navPoint>
        </navMap>
    </ncx>
let $store := xmldb:store('/db', 'test.ncx', $ncx)
let $doc := doc('/db/test.ncx')
for $navPoint in $doc//ncx:navPoint
return
    update value $navPoint/@playOrder with (count($node/ancestor::ncx:navPoint) + count($navPoint/preceding::ncx:navPoint) + 1)
```

Comment: An alternate approach to the XPath one would be to use `index-of(//navPoints, $navPoint)`

Comment: Your solution is so complex I had to mark it as answer. Actually, the solution I have finally used was simply `playOrder="{count($h1/preceding::xhtml:li) + 1}"`—the `$h1` is the variable for headings, for next it would be `$h2` and so on. For the sake of convenience, I will add another answer with this.

Comment: The diagram is amazing! I have just stuck it to my LCD!

Comment: Thanks! As I said, I'd go with generating the right data before you get to the ncx stage. My answer isn't really more complex than yours - we both use XPath to probe the structure of the data. You just had access to data that wasn't in the original post! ;) Glad you liked the diagram. I have it pinned to my board too!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the solution was pretty simple in my case. I am generating the NCX file during collecting of all entries for epub (the file does not exist before the operation). For me it works to generate it from the TOC file, which is produced in preceding steps during the process.

For generating `nav` for TOC I use:

```
<nav epub:type='toc'>
  <ol>{
      for $sect in $chaps
      let $name := replace($sect/@name, "OEBPS/", "")
      return
        for $one in $sect//xhtml:h1
        return
          <li>
            <a href='{$name || '#' || $one/@id}'>{$one/text()[not(ancestor-or-self::xhtml:sup)]}</a>{
              if ($one/parent::*//xhtml:h2 and xs:integer($head-level) ge 2) then
                <ol>{
                    for $two in $one/parent::*//xhtml:h2
                    return
                      <li>
                        <a href='{$name || '#' || $two/@id}'>{$two//text()[not(ancestor-or-self::xhtml:sup)]}</a>{
                          if ($two/parent::*//xhtml:h3 and xs:integer($head-level) ge 3) then
                            <ol>{
                                for $three in $two/parent::*//xhtml:h3
                                return
                                  <li>
                                  … and so on.
```

For NCX’s navMap I use:

```
<navMap>
  <navPoint id='title-page' playOrder='1'>
    <navLabel>
      <text>Title Page</text>
    </navLabel>
    <content src='title-page.xhtml'/>
  </navPoint>{
    (: For every item in the $toc, I count preceding items + I add a number of parents, which are
    items also (I guess to, it simply works! :)
    for $h1 in $toc//xhtml:nav/xhtml:ol/xhtml:li
    return
      <navPoint id='{$h1/xhtml:a/@href}' playOrder='{count($h1/preceding::xhtml:li) + 2}'>
        <navLabel>
          <text>{$h1/xhtml:a/text()[not(ancestor-or-self::xhtml:sup)]}</text>
        </navLabel>
        <content src='{$h1/xhtml:a/@href}'/>{
          for $h2 in $h1/xhtml:ol/xhtml:li
          return
            <navPoint id='{$h2/xhtml:a/@href}' playOrder='{count($h2/preceding::xhtml:li) + 3}'>
              <navLabel>
                <text>{$h2/xhtml:a/text()[not(ancestor-or-self::xhtml:sup)]}</text>
              </navLabel>
              <content src='{$h2/xhtml:a/@href}'/>
              … and so on.
```

The particular solution for `playOrder` is:

```
playOrder='{count($h1/preceding::xhtml:li) + 2}'
```

… which means I am counting all preceding headings included in the TOC + adding a number of particular level I am counting for. It might be replaced with proper counting of parents or so but this gives me always the right result. I was not able to make counting of parents/ancestors work.